# Automounting a USB flash drive on Fedora 16

Tags: usb-flash-drive, fedora, automount

How do I get Fedora 16 to automount my USB devices? USB flash drives will only mount if plugged in before I log in to my account. If I insert any flash drive after log in, the light on the USB flash disk won't even turn on.

Comment: Question is missing important details, like if your running a plain WM or a complete DE.  I know the answer either way.. but one might be an error, the other an addition.

Comment: I'm currently running Gnome 3. I found out that it has to do with the usb ports being powered down when not in use. When the laptop is plugged in to the AC the usb ports work fine.

Comment: can you put your result after executing this commands? fdisk -l